# Changing column to rows in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table that has month, 2022 (values) and 2023(values). 2022 and 2023 are quantity. What I wanted to create is a table that can join both 2022 and 2023 into a single column and at the same time, month will consist of Jan, 2022 and Jan 2023 (for example).

[image]

This is the initial table.

the final table will looks like this:

[image].

PS: I am using power bi and wanted to create a table

I have tried to concatenate it but got issue while trying to assess the month column.

Comment: Please add your sample data as copiable text along with expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rotate the data, once it's done the rest is simple.

To do so you can apply this code in avanced Editor:

```
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"ProductID", "SaleRepID", "Month"}, "Year", "Sales")
```

After that you need to concatinate the 2 column Month and Year:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "YearMonth", each [Month] & " " & [Year])
```

And finally you can remove the unwanted column:

```
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Month", "Year"})
```

Hope this helps